# How to change the zoom level of a Google Sheet in PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to change the zoom level of a Google Sheet that I am generating with the Google Sheets API in PHP.
I have tried creating the sheet and using this code to change the zoom level:

```
            $requests = [
                new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
                    'updateSheetProperties' => [
                        'properties' => [
                            'sheetId' => $sheetID,
                            'zoom'=>$zoomNumber
                        ],
                        'fields'=> 'sheetZoom'
                    ],
                ])
            ];
```

But it does not work.
How should I set the zoom level of a Google Sheet and why does my code not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display zoom is a feature of the web browser instead of a property of a Google Sheet. You cannot set it on the server side. You may want to set things like column widths and font sizes to make the content fit some particular screen size.